# Python web2py save an image from an http post

Tags: python, web2py

i'm trying to upload an image to a server (pythonanywhere.com) with a python script using web2py, so i can make some changes to the image and save it...i will use the script in a terminal and upload the image via curl like that:

```
curl -i -F filedata=@image.jpg http://my_username.pythonanywhere.com/DocScanner/default/upload
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: how to upload the image via POST

Comment: Are you asking how to write the view at `/DocScanner/default/upload`?

Comment: no, the code to upload a file, if i send an image with curl, how i can recieve the image and save it using python ?

Answer (score 2):

That's build in to the web2py `SQLFORM`. Add an `upload` field and web2py will stream the file to disk with a safe name and it will return the name to your code. Have a look at the web2py book which documents `SQLFORM` and `upload` fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os    

def decode_image3(src):
    import base64
    import re
    import uuid
    result = re.search("data:image/(?P<ext>.*?);base64,(?P<data>.*)", src, re.DOTALL)
    if result:
        ext = result.groupdict().get("ext")
        data = result.groupdict().get("data")

    else:
        raise Exception("Do not parse!")

    # 2, base64 decoding
    img = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)

    # 3, the binary file is saved
    filename = "{}.{}".format(uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    completeName = os.path.join(request.folder,'uploads', filename)
    with open(completeName, "wb") as f:
        f.write(img)

    return filename


@request.restful()
def Image2():
    response.view = 'generic.json'

    def POST(**vars):
        image = decode_image3(request.vars.image)
        completeName = os.path.join(request.folder,'uploads', image)
        stream = open(completeName, 'rb')
        if os.path.exists(completeName):
            rv = os.remove(completeName)
        save = db.test.insert(image=stream, age=34)
        return dict(msg=save)

    return locals()
```